# Uso de php en un proyecto de angular en hosting compartido

Tags: php, angular, hosting

Hice una pagina web con **Angular**, se conecta a una *base de datos* desde **PHP**, funcionando como mi API Rest; utilizando Xamp lo hice funcionar localmente pero al querer subirlo a un **hosting compartido**, generé mi página con el comando `build` de Angular y subí la carpeta como una página normal.

**Ahora el problema es que no sé como hacer y dónde subir mis archivos PHP para lograr la conexión a la base de datos MySQL del hosting.**

Disculpen si mi pregunta es tonta pero no sé cómo hacerlo y no he encontrado información al respecto, gracias.

Comment: Esa información la deberias encontrar en el panel de tu hosting. ¿Que panel tienen?  Si es cpanel debes crear la base de datos, la cual posiblemente añada un prefijo tipo "micuentacpanel_" al nombre que le puedas dar, y luego importar sus datos con el phpmyadmin o mediante terminal si te dejan. Una vez tengas los datos debes cambiar los archivos de configuración de la base de datos en tu aplicación con el nuevo nombre y con "localhost" como host, y finalmente no tengo idea de angular y no se si lee los archivos PHP de la carpeta **public_html** o de otra parte

Comment: Gracias, si es un cpanel, ya cree la base de datos y cambie el nombre de la base de datos y el password que coincidan con la base del hosting en mis archivos php, angular crea un servicio donde hace peticiones http a una dirección, esta es donde segun en xampp se almacenan los archivos php que le responden a la pagina con la información de la base de datos, subi los archivos php en la carpeta public_html pero no me funciona, el host al que hago la petición es al localhost en el puerto 80, tal ves deba cambiar el puerto?

Comment: No creo que tengas un problema de puerto, a menos que las peticiones sean https, con lo cual deberia ser el 443 si no me equivoco.  A ver, los archivos que subas a public_html se corresponden con la raiz de tu dominio alojado en cpanel, por lo tanto suponiendo que has subido esos archivos en una subcarpeta denominada **php/** dentro del **public_html/**, para acceder a ellos debes usar **`http://midominio.com/php`** y **NO** **`http://locahost/php`** pues estamos hablando de un compartido con decenas o centenares o miles de dominios o millones o trillones o tropocientos mil millones :-D

Comment: funciono, almacene los archivos php en el subdirectorio php y aun no funcionaba, cambie localhost por el dominio y funciono, muchas gracias, aun me queda mucho que aprender.

Comment: No hace falta que los pongas ahi, los puedes dejar en public_html y llamarlos mediante `http://midominio.com`... eso solo era un ejemplo... o ponlos en una carpeta llamada `para_angular` o algo asi. De este modo puedes poner un index.php o index.html en el public_html y mostrar informacion normal de tu dominio como una pagina de presentacion